# PySpark: Compare array values in one dataFrame with array values in another dataFrame to get the intersection

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two DataFrames:

```py
l1 = [(['hello','world'],), (['stack','overflow'],), (['hello', 'alice'],), (['sample', 'text'],)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(l1)

l2 = [(['big','world'],), (['sample','overflow', 'alice', 'text', 'bob'],), (['hello', 'sample'],)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(l2)
```

**df1:**

```
["hello","world"]
["stack","overflow"]
["hello","alice"]
["sample","text"]
```

**df2:**

```
["big","world"]
["sample","overflow","alice","text","bob"]
["hello", "sample"]
```

For every row in df1, I want to calculate the number of times all the words in the array occur in df2.

For example, the first row in df1 is `["hello","world"]`. Now, I want to check df2 for the intersection of `["hello","world"]` with every row in df2.

```
|                  ARRAY                    | INTERSECTION | LEN(INTERSECTION)| 
|["big","world"]                            |["world"]     | 1                |
|["sample","overflow","alice","text","bob"] |[]            | 0                |   
|["hello","sample"]                         |["hello"]     | 1                |
```

Now, I want to return the `sum(len(interesection))`. Ultimately I want the resulting df1 to look like this:

**df1 result:**

```
       ARRAY               INTERSECTION_TOTAL
| ["hello","world"]    |      2                 |
| ["stack","overflow"] |      1                 |
| ["hello","alice"]    |      2                 |
| ["sample","text"]    |      3                 |
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd focus on avoiding Cartesian product first. I'd try to explode and join

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, monotonically_increasing_id

df1_ = (df1.toDF("words")
  .withColumn("id_1", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .select("*", explode("words").alias("word")))

df2_ = (df2.toDF("words")
    .withColumn("id_2", monotonically_increasing_id())
    .select("id_2", explode("words").alias("word")))

(df1_.join(df2_, "word").groupBy("id_1", "id_2", "words").count()
    .groupBy("id_1", "words").sum("count").drop("id_1").show())
+-----------------+----------+                                                  
|            words|sum(count)|
+-----------------+----------+
|   [hello, alice]|         2|
|   [sample, text]|         3|
|[stack, overflow]|         1|
|   [hello, world]|         2|
+-----------------+----------+
```

If intermediate values are not needed it could be simplified to:

```
df1_.join(df2_, "word").groupBy("words").count().show()
+-----------------+-----+                                                       
|            words|count|
+-----------------+-----+
|   [hello, alice]|    2|
|   [sample, text]|    3|
|[stack, overflow]|    1|
|   [hello, world]|    2|
+-----------------+-----+
```

and you could omit adding ids.